# Add Logo on the left of the toolbar in the PWA starter kit

Tags: polymer, polymer-starter-kit

how can you add a logo on the left of the toolbar in the PWA starter kit?
I am using this PWA starter kit:https://pwa-starter-kit.appspot.com/

The result should be like the toolbar on the polymer website:

https://www.polymer-project.org/

Answer (score 1):

As the `app-toolbar` structure

```
<app-toolbar class="toolbar-top" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
  <button class="menu-btn" title="Menu"><!----><svg height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24"><path d="M3 18h18v-2H3v2zm0-5h18v-2H3v2zm0-7v2h18V6H3z"></path></svg><!----></button>
  <div main-title=""><!---->my app<!----></div>
</app-toolbar>
```

Replacing `<div main-title=""><!---->my app<!----></div>` with your logo or event a custom layout should work

For usage of `app-toolbar` component, go [webcomponents.org docs](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-layout/elements/app-toolbar)